# Meaning of reduced relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

> There were many employees working very hard.

It can be written as:

1. There were many employees who were working very hard.

Or,

2. There were many employees who worked very hard.

How to know which one is the intended meaning?

Comment: What do you think the difference between #1 and #2 is?

Comment: I know the difference but want to know"how to know in which sense the sentence will be interpreted.?"

Comment: 1. describes a situation in which many employees are *at that very moment in time* working very hard.  2. describes a situation in which many employees exist who *are in the habit* of working hard, but aren't necessarily working at all at that particular moment.  It's the difference between the past continuous tense (1.) and the simple past (2.) - I believe that the reduced relative clause has the same meaning as (1.), but **not** as (2.).

Comment: After all, it's called a **reduced** relative clause for a reason.  What exactly is being *reduced*?  The clause "who were working very hard" gets reduced to just "working very hard" i.e. "who were" is dropped

Comment: While *worked* is an entirely different form.  The clause "who worked very hard" can't reduce to "working very hard" because that would be changing the form of the word, not just omitting the "who" part of the clause.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck But there are many examples on internet that show "v+ing " can be used in simple tense as well as in continuous tense.

Comment: A girl who works at a pub has won a lottery.
A girl working at a pub has won a lottery.➡ It's an example.

Comment: In that case, I'm not clear on what your question is.  Those last two sentences in your comment may have the same meaning, but that doesn't mean that the second is a reduced version of the first.  They're *syntactically* different even if they're *semantically* the same.